# How do I model this in DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am testing out DynamoDB for a serverless app I am building. I have successfully modeled all of my application's query patterns except one. I was hoping someone could provide some guidance. Here are the details:

**Data Model**

There are three simple entities: User (~1K records), Product (~100K), ActionItem (~100/product).

- A User has a many-to-many relationship with Product.
- A Product has a one-to-many relationship with ActionItem.

**The Workflow**

There's no concept of "Team" for this app. Instead, a user is assigned a set of products which they (and others) are responsible for managing. The user picks the oldest items from their products' action item list, services the item and then closes it.

The use case I am trying to model is: *As a user, show me all action items for products to which I am assigned.*

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really only two options...

If you can store the list of products within the 400KB limit of DDB record, then you could have a record like so...
Hash Key: userID
Sort KEY: "ASSIGNED_PRODUCTS"

Otherwise,
Hash key: UserID
Sort key: "#PRODUCT#10001-54502"

userID in the above might be the raw userid, or if using a GSI, might be something like "#USER#user-id"

Comment: Thanks. I'll try denormalizing this per user.